# Considerations for mismatched 18650's in series

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I'm building a large battery pack. I'm in the planning stage, collecting parts and such, but my goal is to have something like a 4s9p or 4s10p arrangement. The cells I have vary though. Not by a ton, but a hundred or so mAh here and there. All of the parallel sets would be identical cells that were all originally used together, but each set in series would have slightly different capacities. What considerations do I need to keep in mind with this sort of setup? I know it's not advised to use mismatched cells, but I might not have a lot of choice in the matter. I know I'll at least have to have good balancing, anything else to keep in mind?

Comment: This would not be a very *wise*/*sane* setup. LiPO batteries are highly sensitive to overcharge/over-discharge scenarios, and each cell requires independent balancing in order to maintain correct function & best cell-life. - Parallel cells are likely to cause severe damage to each other after a few uses, and mis-matched serial strands (whether of single cells, or of parallel sets of cells) will derate with the weakest link.

Comment: There are, however, charge-controller chipsets already made, that will allow you to connect several cells to the same circuit, with each cell being both charged, and discharged, as an individual cell. This would allow you to get peak energy usage from every single cell, without the damaging effects from the series & parallel connections (especially since you're using intentionally mismatched cells).

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB If you are suggesting adding an individual charger/discharger that steps the voltage up/down from a common bus for every single cell, that doesn't make sense with 18650's as it would be so costly that it would be cheaper to just *buy brand new cells*.

Comment: Li-Ion, not Li-Po. Laptop batteries and the like. They're all perfectly functional and have been kept in the same sets they were always in with the exception being I put them all in parallel instead of series. (So like, all 9 cells from the laptop battery in parallel instead of 3s3p)

Comment: @jms on another question (sometime last year) I had found a TI charge controller chip that was less than 1/2 the per-cell cost of anything better than XXXfire 18650s...so still far cheaper than replacing with all new, matched 18650s.

Comment: The main consideration is how to extinguish the likely fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All of the parallel sets would be identical cells that were all originally used together, but each set in series would have slightly different capacities.

You want to do exactly the opposite. A 1 Ah cell in parallel with a 2 Ah cell behaves as a single 3 Ah cell, but a 1 Ah cell in series with a 2 Ah cell yields a 2S battery that can only be discharged 1 Ah, wasting the mismatching capacity of the better cell. If you discharge the hypothetical battery further in order to benefit from the capacity of the better 2 Ah cell, you will overdischarge and ruin the 1Ah cell.

If you insist on reusing salvaged batteries (I wouldn't), you want to combine the mismatching cells into parallel sets of equal capacity, and then place those in series. You also **must add overcharge protection, undercharge protection and balancing** to your battery in some form or another.

As pointed out by Robherc, if the internal resistances of parallel cells are vastly different (and not in proportion of their differing capacities), you can exceed the maximum charge and discharge rates of individual cells in a parallel set. For example:

You have a battery of two parallel 1 Ah cells rated for 3 A discharge, but one cell has an internal resistance of 0.1 Ω and the other has degraded to 1 Ω. The battery is fully charged to 4.2 V, and you begin a 4 A discharge. The battery voltage will immediately fall to† 3.84 V due to the internal resistance, but the current is *not* shared equally. Initially **the 0.1 Ω cell will be discharging at 3.64 A, exceeding the rating, while the 1 Ω cell will only provide 0.36 A**. However as the 0.1 Ω discharges much faster, the 1 Ω cell will eventually catch up during the discharge and start to share the load (assuming that it doesn't combust first). Also, the 0.1 Ω cell will wear much faster with subsequent charge-discharge cycles, slowly equalizing itself with the more degraded cell in the pack.

While this is a rather extreme example, you should still throw out cells that differ greatly in the product of cell capacity and internal resistance, and de-rate the charge and discharge rates from the theoretical values accordingly.

---

† Internal resistance of the battery as a whole:
  1/(1/0.1 Ω + 1/1 Ω) ≈ 0.091 Ω
Voltage loss over the internal resistance:
4 A * 0.091 Ω = 0.364 V
Remaining (true) battery voltage:
4.2 V - 0.364 V = 3.836 V ≈ 3.84 V

Comment: A 1Ah cell in parallel with a 2Ah cell represents an extreme likelihood of *parallel batteries with differing internal resistances*. That scenario is highly damaging to battery life for *any* battery chemistry (even lead-acid...don't believe me, tell a backup-power battery mfgr. that you want to connect 4 of their batteries in parallel, with no shunt resistors & listen to their heads explode).

Comment: In mismatched internal resistance parallel battery sets, the battery(s) with lower internal resistance gets both charged & discharged too quickly (often unintentionally violating safe charge/discharge rate limits), while the one(s) with higher internal resistance actually add very little to the set.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I agree that it's far from optimal (I don't suggest doing it, as you can see from my answer), but you cannot deny that placing different capacities in series is *worse*. It's a recipe for both overcharging and overdischarging the worst cells, and reduces the effective capacity to that of the lowest parallel set.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB If OP and other people are going to do it *anyway*, wouldn't it be better to give advice about how to do it in the least bad way rather than just saying "don't do it". Also, (theoretically as you should avoid doing this with real world batteries) differing internal resistances have no effect, as long as they scale with the cell capacities. A 1 Ah 2 ohm cell placed in parallel with a 2 Ah 1 ohm cell will have both charging and discharging in the same amount of time.

Comment: I agree, this is not a bad answer. And if it's amended so that it mentions that you should add an appropriate safety factor to the discharge rating, in order to take into account the varying internal resistances of the cells that make up each parallel group, it would become a straight out good answer IMO.

Comment: I haven't read the comments yet, but I didn't firm vote it. This is actually a good idea. Instead of putting mismatched sets in series, put mismatched cells in parallel so that the series sets match each other. I'll do the math to figure out how I'd need to arrange them. I also planned to have over charge/discharge protection for each parallel pack and balance charging for the series. Thank you!

Comment: As far as internal resistance and all that, the most I plan on drawing from the entire pack would be 5A, at most. All of the individual cells are capable of that and often the output will be much less. Charging will be less than that too, probably 4A max.

Comment: @jms I still contend, however, that wiring mismatched batteries in series is safer for the batteries then parallel. In series, you *will* have to reduce the used capacity of the pack to that of the lowest-capacity battery, but it will save having the better batteries be aged faster than the worse ones in a parallel circuit.

Comment: The lowest capacity battery I have is like 2200mAh, and the highest is 2600. I have a large set to choose from though so I might not necessarily use those. In addition, according to my research, the lowest maximum output is still in the 15-20A range, well over what I plan to pull from them. I've been charging the matched parallel packs of 9 cells with a 1A charger. It works, just takes a long time. For what I'll be using this for that's totally ok with me. Slow charge over time from a cigarette lighter plug in the car.

Comment: @jms How would this be for a balancing charger? [4 cells 8A w/balancing Li-ion Lithium...](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-cells-8A-w-balancing-Li-ion-Lithium-18650-14450-Battery-Input-Ouput-Protection/111172932781) And would a balance charger like that allow me to charge the batteries while actually using them? For example, the battery pack will charge from a car cigarette lighter, but it will have USB outputs to charge a phone. Could I charge it while a phone was plugged in and charging from it?

Comment: @HaLo2FrEeEk That board has a low voltage cutoff of 2.7 V per cell, and a charging cutoff of 4.35 V per cell. Those limits are extremely aggressive, and not all li-ion batteries are rated for such a voltage range. Don't use that board for random salvaged batteries, 4.35 V could cause them to vent! Look for a range around 3.0 V to 4.2 V. Also, be aware that the board you posted has a current limit of just 8 A. Do not buy multiple boards and place them in series if that's how you plan to get a 8s pack, the protection circuitry won't cut off properly.

Comment: @HaLo2FrEeEk those balancing and protection boards are **not chargers**. They can only balance a battery and disconnect it from the output if something goes wrong, they cannot actually charge a battery from a power supply. You need a separate circuit to do that. A 4s pack would range in voltage from 12 V (fully discharged) to 16.8 V (fully charged), so you need a charger that can step up the voltage of a 12 V cigarette lighter socket to the battery voltage.

Comment: You technically can't charge and discharge a battery simultaneously, the battery itself will just see the difference between the charger output current and the load current. It's always either charging or discharging but never both at the same time. Yes, you could place a load on the battery while you are charging it, you'd just route some charging current somewhere else (and slow or reverse the charging process).

Comment: @jms Thank you for the information. I'm fairly new to working with lithium batteries, so I'm trying to soak up all the information I can. I figured I'd have to step up the cigarette lighter voltage, realized that right after I posted. I have single-cell (/parallel pack) charging boards that take 5V in and limit the current to 1A, I also have a step-down CC/CV regulator for battery charging. Could I put one of those on each individual cell/pack and connect the outputs to a balance circuit?